# Adding multiple Numbers with decimal shows long trail of numbers

Tags: floating-point, numbers, floating-accuracy

I am trying to add few decimal numbers from form input field which is like:

```
var total = Number(11000.2)+Number(10000.1)+Number(10762.4);
consol.log(total);
```

consol shows 31762.700000000004

I don't understand from where its getting addition values (00000000004) and showing .700000000004.

Can anyone please explain what is happening here and what I am missing?

Comment: This is called floating point precision error. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Also, this has nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: Try `console.log(Number(total.toFixed(1)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an age old issue to do with floating point arithmetic. You can read more about it in lots of posts like this: [How to deal with floating point number precision in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/elegant-workaround-for-javascript-floating-point-number-problem)

The typical simple solution to it is to treat decimals as integers then to divide them back to decimals later. Like so:

```
var a = 0.2;
var b = 0.1;

var r = a + b; // r == 0.300000000004

var r = (10*a + 10*b)/10; // r == 0.3
```

In your case I'd do it like this:

```
var factor = 10; 
var total = (factor*11000.2 + factor*10000.1 + factor*10762.4) / factor;

// total == 31762.7
```